# Gmail is hiding my emails when i scroll to bottom of inbox

Tags: gmail

Its 8/23/2022, And gmail is hiding my emails when i scroll to bottom of inbox and not letting me see old email messages.

See Picture below, I have old mails messages that exist below the scrollbars bottom position.

[image]

If I delete the last message, then an older previous message fill this position, but yet is not visibile.

How to fix this problem with gmail so that I can see old messages?

Comment: Not only was it off topic, but you are not looking. If you look above right, you will see "1 - 50 of 5,534 >`, and clicking that chevron allows you to go to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of conversations that can be shown in Gmail page in a web browser in desktop mode is 100. According to your screenshot, your account is set to show 50 conversations by page. To change the page size go to Settings > General. The setting name is Maximum page size.

Regarding deleting the last message in the page and not showing the next message, you might click the Gmail button to load new messages, refresh the browswer tab or navigate to the next page. If you want that this work in a different without using an browser automation tool, then you should submit your feedback directly to Google. To do this, click the help button (the icon is a circle with a question mark inside, near to the top right),  then **Send feedback to Google**, fill the form and submit it.

Regarding your [own answer](https://superuser.com/a/1741663/152004) mentioning that the Gmail App (for Android or iOS) doesn't have this problem, it's just an "illusion", very old conversations are downloaded as the user scroll down, they might be purged automatically.

Related from Web Applications SE: [How to set up Gmail to show more than 20 results per page when searching?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13161/88163)

Answer (score -1):

For what's worth, the google Gmail App doesn't have this problem.

However, using a cellphone web-browser to read your email limits the number of previous emails that you can see.